# Проверка строки на наличие символов не являющихся пробелами

Tags: c#

Как сделать проверку того что строка не состоит целиком из пробелов?

```
private bool IsAddCancel(string? data)
        {
            if (data == null || data == " ")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Отмена ввода...\nНажмите любую клавишу для возврата...");
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: Используй  `data.Replace(" ", "");`   (удалишь пробелы), потом проверяй на наличие символов .

Comment: [String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace("...")](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.string.isnullorwhitespace?view=net-7.0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Net Framework 4.0+:

```
private bool IsAddCancel(string? data)
{
  if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(data))
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Отмена ввода...\nНажмите любую клавишу для возврата...");
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Net Framework 3.5-:

```
private bool IsAddCancel(string? data)
{
  char[] trimChars = new char[] { ' ', '\t', '\r', '\n' };
  if (data == null || data.Trim(trimChars).Length == 0)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Отмена ввода...\nНажмите любую клавишу для возврата...");
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```